# Display response of Dropbox API thumbnail() in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropbox-api

I have successfully returned a `thumbnail()` request (using the [Dropbox SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers)) in my rails app, but I don't understand how to process the response. I would like to show the thumbnail on a webpage.

I also tried to save the response to a tmp file, but get a `UndefinedConversionError` ("\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8) error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually doing exactly what you are asking for. What I did was to convert the returned bytes into a base64 string. In C# it's quite easy as there is a convert function to do that.

On the webpage you then have to set the src attribute of a img tag to

```
<img src="data: image/jpg;base64,PlaceBase64StringHere"...../>
```

There is a little overhead in the converted string, but it's very easy to handle and you use the power of the client browser to render the image.